# Github: Why do I need it?

Tags: windows, git, github

I am still quite unsure how to use it, but I just downloaded Git and I was setting it up according to their [web page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git). The section on password caching says if I don't have to enter my password every time, I can use Github for Windows. I was confused so I found a question here asking "what is github anyway?" and the answers say it's a website or it's web hosting. So I clicked the Github for Windows link on the how-to page and next thing I know I'm downloading an .exe file.

- If Github is a website, why do I need an .exe file?
- Is the only benefit to not type in your password?
- How does Github relate to Git Bash?
- Are Git and Git Bash the same thing?

P.S. I have 2 computers, 1 is XP and the other Win7. The downloads I'm talking about were on the XP but I will also put it on the 7 if I can determine that I need it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, except Tim. I suppose he expects the only people who want to learn something should already know it before they start. I know some Unix so I'm pretty comfortable with either (Tim, don't look so shocked). I guess I'll mess around with them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- How does Github relate to Git Bash?
- Are Git and Git Bash the same thing?

The latter question first: Not exactly. Git is a collection of programs allowing you to track changes in source files (really any kind of non-binary file and some binary files). Git Bash is one of the ways to actually run Git on Windows. Since Git was written for Linux, it relies heavily on Unix-like functionality which isn't present in Windows; that problem is solved by msysGit, a package containining Git and a Unix compatibility layer.

Git Bash is the version of the Bash shell, provided as part of msysGit. If you're familiar with the Windows command prompt, Bash is basically like a Unix/Linux equivalent. It opens a command-line window where you can type Git commands or other commands.

The former question: GitHub for Windows is another, GUI-based Git client. I don't have it myself to check, but from what I've found online it looks like GitHub for Windows includes msysGit also, and thus Git Bash. But you shouldn't need to use Git Bash much (if at all) with GitHub for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

the exe is simply a windows interface to sync code to the github website (where you can track changes and then download it to your other computer)

normally you use a command line interface to control git (bash is a linux command line- 'git bash' would be for linux command line)

Answer (score 2):

Stick with msysgit on the command line. The GUI client leaves a lot to be desired. you don't get command history, you don't get tab completion, you don't get scripting and you don't get piping.

You will also find a lot more material on line to help you if you use msysgit or git on Linux.

Comment: +1 the GUI client is a nightmare, much better to stick to the command line.

Comment: Browsing history is a very poor experience in command line though.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Disagreed. If you know how to set up your .gitconfig, it's not.

Comment: `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` or setup a custom log formatter.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer You can list them in a pretty manner, but you can't see what code actually changed in each commit.  I'd say clicking around in a UI is a better experience.

Comment: git log -p will help you there

Comment: @R0MANARMY `git diff [hash]^1 [hash]`

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer and that's a better experience than clicking on a list item in a UI?

Comment: @R0MANARMY If you know your shit, yes.

Answer (score 2):

git is a version control system.

Github is a web service providing webspace that is accessible via the git version control system.

git can be used without Github.

There are several clients that "implement" git (e.g. TortoiseGit or the "original" git) on various platforms.

Github for Windows is an application facilitating work with Github, but not necessary for using Github or git.

Answer (score 1):

You should visit github home, it says following:

"Git is an extremely fast, efficient, distributed version control system ideal for the collaborative development of software."

Basically Github is a hosted repository for your software source code. It maintains versioning for your source code files and you have various plans for that. For example if you are planning to host an open source project you can host unlimited of them with free account while if you want private repository you have to start looking for some paid plan.

It's social development environment on top of Git version control system. It similar to SVN, Microsoft VSS but it's hosted while if you use Microsoft VSS, generally we host it on intranet by setting up some VSS Server in network itself.

Windows Binary file (.exe) is the tool to manage your repositories/project directories on GitHub and get it synced on local / repos. So more like VSS Client but much much different at the same time.